# Inner product property in a convex set.

Tags: analysis, proof-verification

> **Question:** Let $C \subset \mathbb R^n$ be a convex set. If $x \in \mathbb R^{n}$ and $\overline{x} \in C$ are such that $$\|x - \overline{x}\| = d(x,C)$$ Show that $$\langle x - \overline{x}, y - \overline{x}\rangle \leq 0 , \forall y \in C$$

**Attempt:** If we take $\color {red} {u = \overline{x} - x}$ and $v = y - \overline{x}$ we may write $$\|u\| \leq \|u + tv\| , \forall t \in [0,1]$$

since $u + tv \in C$. Then squaring both sides we get $$\begin{align}\langle u , u\rangle &\leq \langle u + tv, u+ tv  \rangle \\&= \langle u , u\rangle + 2t \langle u , v\rangle  +t^2\langle v , v\rangle , \, \, \forall t \in [0,1]\\&\implies 2t \langle u , v\rangle  +t^2\|v\|^2\geq 0 ,\,\,\forall t \in [0,1] \\&\implies  t\Big[2 \langle u , v\rangle  +t\|v\|^2 \Big]\geq 0 ,\,\, \forall t \in [0,1]\end{align}$$

Assuming $ \langle u , v\rangle <0$ for a moment, we would have

$$ t\Big[2 \langle u , v\rangle  +t\|v\|^2 \Big] < 0$$

for $0 \leq t < -\frac{2\langle u,v\rangle}{\|v\|^2}$, which is a contradiction. Then we conclude that $\langle u , v\rangle \geq 0$ thus the result follows.

I couldn't convince myself that $u + tv \in C$, although I've tried some many ways I couldn't get the result in any other way.

I know that if $C$ is convex then for any $u,v \in C \implies u + tv \in C$. The problem is to show that $u \in C$ in fact.

Is there any major flaw? Something I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, $C$ is convex iff $(\color{red}{1 - t})u + tv \in C$ for all $u,v\in C$ and $t\in [0,1]$. With $u = \bar{x} - x$, $v = y - \bar{x}$ and $t\in [0,1]$, we have

$$u + tv = (1 - t)\bar{x} + ty - x.$$

Since $C$ is convex and both $\bar{x}$ and $y$ belong to $C$, so does $z := (1 - t)\bar{x} + ty \in C$. Hence

$$\|u + tv\| = \|z - x\| \ge d(x,C) = \|x - \bar{x}\|.$$

Comment: But then $u + tv$ isn't necessarily in $C$ right?

Comment: Correct. For example, let $C = [0,1]$, $u = v = 1$, and $t = 1/2$. Then $u + tv = 3/2$, which is not in $C$.

Comment: That's it!! Thanks a lot. I had drafted this, just didn't fully understand it.